# Doing an independent study as a high schooler but can't seem to figure out the values that need to be used to get pearson's correlation coefficient

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

Here's the database, it's a rather small one: https://www.theadgalternative.com/world_cup_data.html

I dont understand what my N, X, and Y values would be since nothing is really quantitative.

I'm trying to find out if there's a relationship exists between coming out victorious in the shootout and if the victorious team had taken the first shot (WKF).

If that's figured out, what other statistical methods (besides descriptive stats) can I do?

Comment: What kind of descriptive statistics have you been using so far, and why do you think it's not informative for your purpose?

Comment: @J-J-J Hello! I think I worded it incorrectly. I meant I had already thought of descriptive statistics and so I wanted some other recommendations. Technically, I haven't done any calculations yet since I can't figure out the quantitative data to begin with.

Comment: If you try some simple descriptive statistics, e.g. the distribution of Y/N for the WKF variable, you'll see that on its own it's quite informative. By the way, if this is a homework question, you should mention it, so we can get an idea of what is expected from you and give you more adequate guidance.

Comment: You have a variable or whether or not the team had the first kick, and you can pair those with the win/loss outcome for that team, right?